# Why did G. Britain & France not declare war on USSR in 1939?

Tags: world-war-two

When Germany and the USSR invaded Poland in Sept 1939 from different side of Poland, France and Gt Britain declared war on Germany only.  Why?

Comment: And covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_invasion_of_Poland#International_reaction).